# What time format is this JSON

Tags: json

I'm looking at an example with the JSON input for the date as this:

```
1136005200000
```

It corresponds to the date of

```
12/30/05
```

What time format this is? I'm relatively new to this and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Answer (score 3):

Unix time in milliseconds, i.e. what [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns.